# R.id.field no longer recognized

Tags: android, r.java-file

I was adding a tab change listener edit code no where near my problem and once I finished a call to `R.id.edit_details_button` was no longer resolving. I think the entirety of the code I added was

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
...
import android.widget.ImageView;
...
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
...
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                if("image".equals(tabId)) {
                    File file = getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("/sdcard/" + mPrefs.getInt("id", 0) + ".jpg");
                    if(file.exists()) {
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
                    } else {
                        ImageView image  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        Resources res = getResources();
                        image.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
                    }
                }
            }});
...
```

I Ctrl+Z'd until it undid my changes and it fixed the error. My redo queue wasn't as long as my undo queue so I had to make my changes again and after that I closed eclipse to hope it would fix the problem.

In my strings.xml I have `<string name="edit_details_button">Edit details</string>`, but I notice in my R.java file there is a field defined edit_menu_button such as I had in my last project."Fixing Project Properties" doesn't fix it.

I tried manually editing the R.java field to the value I need, but it reverted after the manual edit. I tried deleting R.java and it regenerated it with the wrong file name.

Comment: Don't manually edit R.java or delete it - it can cause problems and, as you found out, it usually doesn't solve anything. Have you tried 'Project -> Clean..."? This will delete any auto-generated files and re-generate them and re-build the project. Also, check all of your code files to see if ther is an `import android.R` entry or in fact any explicit `import` for any `R` class. If you find any, remove them and then 'Clean'.

Comment: That was exactly it. I had an `import` for an `R` from my other project somehow. This isn't how you accept your response as an answer is it?

Comment: Glad it helped. I've converted my comment to an answer. To accept it just click the 'check` mark to the left of my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manually edit `R.java` or delete it - it can cause problems and, as you found out, it usually doesn't solve anything.

Have you tried 'Project -> Clean..."? This will delete any auto-generated files and re-generate them and re-build the project.

Also, check all of your code files to see if there is an `import android.R` entry or in fact any explicit `import` for any `R` class. If you find any, remove them and then 'Clean'

Comment: import android.R entry was exactly the issue. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Happy to help. Stuff like this happens to me sometimes usually when refactoring code. It's a bit of a pain but you'll get used to knowing what to look for.